# Nativescript - setting a background-image for the whole page

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to set a background-image to the entire page.

In the page element, I set a class.

I set the css class to:

background-image: url('res://bg.png');

The file is in my (App_Resources/Android/drawable_nodpi) folder.

But the image is not being set.

If I change the background-image to background-color - it does set the color.

Comment: Try removing the file extension (*.png). I have tested this case with this application and it works as expected on my side https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/noDpi

Comment: Thank you. All the examples I've seen had the extension. If you upgrade your response to an "ANSWER" I'd be happy to tag - unless I can tag your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the file extension (*.png) will do the job.

[Sample application](http://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/) and it works as expected on my side